# Как называются должности программистов

Tags: работа

Занимаюсь поиском работы связанной с программированием в ниже перечисленных предметных областях и пытаюсь понять как правильно называются наиболее популярные (востребованные) должности - т.е. какие слова должны быть в заголовке объявления о вакансии. После поиска по сайтам с предложениями работы у меня осталась каша в голове. Если кто-нибудь владеет такой информацией, поделитесь, пожалуйста. Если кто-то сможет привести также английские эквиваленты названий должностей - будет вообще замечательно. Вот список интересующих меня предметных областей:

- Формальные языки и синтаксический анализ (в частности, создание компиляторов)
- Разработка ОС
- Цифровое аудио и видео, цифровая обработка сигналов
- Компьютерная графика (аналитическая геометрия, линейная алгебра и т. п.)
- Компьютерная математика

Спасибо!

Comment: Широкий спектр интересов. А вот названия должностей в вакансиях очень часто не отражают того, чем вам реально могут предложить заняться.

Comment: Это в Канаде или...?

Comment: @Suvitruf Да, в Канаде

Comment: @avp Как же тогда быть? Какую стратегию поиска использовать?

Comment: Вы не переживайте - в программировании нет такого, что определил свой путь, и всё. При наличии опыта - нужно всего месяц-два на адаптацию к новой деятельности и языкам. А чтобы этот опыт был - надо действовать, а не искать работу мечты :) Главное для опыта - идти работать туда, где несколько других программистов есть.

Comment: @Ruslan, про поиск в Канаде ничего сказать не могу (только в Москве)

Comment: @avp Будьте добры, подскажите про Москву. Возможно это наведет меня на мысль. Или, может быть, я смогу адаптировать Вашу информацию к канадским реалиям

Comment: Computer Vision Engineer/Computervision/Image Processing/Research engineer/

Comment: @Viacheslav Vedenin Да, действительно, поиск по этим ключевым словам дает интересные результаты. Спасибо!

Comment: можете еще попробовать Phd/Master degree и дальше специальность, так как это часто именно более научные вакансии

Comment: @Ruslan, в Москве основной путь хорошего трудоустройства это личные связи (т.е. через знакомых)

Answer (score 3):

- Ведущий (senior), cтарший (middle), младший (junior) и т.п. **программист (programmer)** на таком-то ЯП
- Ведущий, старший, младший и т.п. **разработчик (developer, engineer)** таких-то систем.

По этим словам, добавляя описание конкретных областей, с очень высокой вероятностью сможете найти адекватное совпадение на сайтах с вакансиями.

А что же касается конкретики в названии должностей (вакансий), то особо на это не полагайтесь, ибо вакансии пишут как правило не программисты, и вполне возможна ситуация, когда ищут "Разработчика ОС", а в объявлении будет значится "Программист на языке С... Обязанности: разработка ОС".

Comment: Что-то очень сомневаюсь, что это ответ на вопрос...

Comment: @Qwertiy "Если кто-то сможет привести также английские эквиваленты названий должностей - будет вообще замечательно" просили слова, слова предоставил, и по этим ключевым словам можно найти вакансии по разработке вышеуказанных продуктов. А вообще присмотритесь к вопросу внимательнее, репутация позволяет ибо.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что ты назвал общие должности, а в вопросе говорится о конкретных областях. Например, разработка ОС - это, вероятно, системный порграммист. Остальные я не знаю или не помню.

Comment: Согласен с @Qwertiy, к тому же эти 3 категории выдуманные и лично я их не воспринимаю серьёзно.

Comment: Кстати, что-то категории на одну съехали. Младший (junior), [без дополнительных слов - middle], старший (senior) и ведущий (lead). @Flippy, категорий 4 и они не выдуманы - они везде есть, не только у программистов.

Comment: А так же не стоит забывать про возможные руководящие должности - руководитель проекта(project manager) и технический директор(chief technology officer). @Qwertiy я вообще сомневаюсь, что для офтопика который пойдет под закрытие, нужен расписанный подробно ответ.

Comment: @AlexKrass, в случае хорошего ответа можно тащить на мету под [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе].